# Borderlands 2 on Ubuntu 12.04 problems

Tags: borderlands-2, ubuntu

Okay so I'm running GNU/Linux Ubuntu 12.04, I'm trying to play Borderlands 2 and I know it will work as other players have success playing the game.
I was told to install the following:

vcredist vcrun2008 vcrun2010 msxml3 winhttp physx

vcredist returned:
"Unknown arg vcredist"

and vcrun2010 gave me this on the installation page:
"HRESULT 0x80070643"

other then that, they all installed fine (I think) I open steam that was installed via Wine and locate to
**~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/SteamApps/common/Borderlands 2/Binaries/Win32**

and I type **wine Borderlands2.exe**

(Note: I also have -NoLauncher on my game's properties for launcher settings thing)
It takes a while to open, the splash screen shows, and then the everything just kinda crashes (Black screen).. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is the terminal log:
http://pastebin.com/i9MR95zf

Comment: You're... trying to play a game like Borderlands over Wine? Isn't Cedega more suited for such things? Though, admittedly, my knowledge about gaming on Linux is almost nonexistent and hopelessly outdated.

Comment: This question is quite old, but _Borderlands 2_ now has a native Linux port that works on Ubuntu, which you may wish to try instead.  It's been available native for over 2 years now.